# Different window.innerWidth between chrome and firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, width

```
html, body { 
     position:absolute; 
     width:100%; 
     height:100%; 
     margin: 0; 
     padding: 0; 
     overflow: hidden; 
}
```

The `window.innerWidth` return different number from FX and chrome
FX return 1429 while Chrome return 1159 ,  Why is the difference and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Are the windows actually the same width on your screen?

Comment: both are at the max size

Comment: I check the firefox developer mode , and it has body's client width 1429 instead of 1159 .. Why is the difference?

Comment: Because they have different amounts of window chrome? Really, there's simply not enough information here to answer.

Comment: Sorry , what extra info I need to provide?

Comment: I think there's ample information here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because the with of the document depends on how much of the viewport is available for the application body.

It will depend on the thickness of the borders of the application, any other plugins which are active etc.

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KZhjc/2/). This will alert the width of the browser, for me chrome is giving 677 while firefox is giving 674

```
var body = $('body')
alert(body.width() + ' - ' + body.innerWidth())
```

Comment: I know this is an old comment but this is not working for me. Chrome is showing a massive difference of 837 to firefox 645 in that demo.

Comment: @MagicLasso I know this is an old comment also but you could check browser Zoom