# Why is (window.innerwidth > 1025) working in all browsers except Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, media-queries, parallax

I'm using (window.innerwidth > 1025) to allow parallax code in windows larger than 1025px wide. This works perfectly in all browsers (Chrome, IE, Safari) except Firefox.

When I remove the first line, the parallax works as expected in Firefox.

```
if (window.innerWidth > 1025){      
        var $window = $(window);
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var pos = $window.scrollTop(); //position of the scrollbar
        var $this = $(this);

        //setup defaults if arguments aren't specified
        if(xpos == null){xpos = "50%"}
        if(adjuster == null){adjuster = 0}
        if(inertia == null){inertia = 0.1}
        if(outerHeight == null){outerHeight = true}

        height = $this.height();
        $this.css({'backgroundPosition': newPos(xpos, outerHeight, adjuster, inertia)}); 

        function newPos(xpos, windowHeight, pos, adjuster, inertia){
            return xpos + " " + Math.round((-((windowHeight + pos) - adjuster) * inertia)) + "px";
        }

        //function to be called whenever the window is scrolled or resized
        function move(pos, height){ 
                $this.css({'backgroundPosition': newPos(xpos, height, pos, adjuster, inertia)}); 
        }

        $window.bind('scroll', function(){ //when the user is scrolling...

            pos = $window.scrollTop(); //position of the scrollbar
            inView(pos, $this);

        })

    }
```

Comment: what do you see when you `console.log(window.innerWidth)`

Comment: you tell us - have you tried debugging? Console log the values, check what your jquery variables turn into, etc?

Comment: Related: [Different window.innerWidth between chrome and firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450874/different-window-innerwidth-between-chrome-and-firefox)

Comment: var $window = $(window);

Can you try change this variable to var $(window) = $('html,body');

Comment: When I used Firebug, I saw the following error (this error is only present when the (window.innerwidth > 1025) is present:

ReferenceError: newPos is not defined
$this.css({'backgroundPosition': newPos(xpos, outerHeight, adjuster, inertia)})

Comment: `console.log(window.innerWidth)` printed out the window width (in this case, it was 1241) (I discovered I was having difficulty due to Firebug, so I deactivated it). I am still getting the following error and am not sure how to resolve it: ReferenceError: newPos is not defined referencing the following line `$this.css({'backgroundPosition': newPos(xpos, outerHeight, adjuster, inertia)}); ` Any help is so appreciated!!

Comment: If it helps, this is the site that I'm working on: http://staging.rico.is/designing/ again, any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!