# Android Firefox JavaScript screen dimensions false?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got following HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
                var w = window.screen.width;
                var h = window.screen.height;
                var s = "Width: " + w + "px<br/>Height: " + h + "px";
                document.body.innerHTML = s;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using Pixel 2 with Chrome gives me result:

```
Width: 412px
Height: 732px
```

And with Firefox, I got result:

```
Width: 414px
Height: 688px
```

Why the result are not the same? It looks to me that Firefox has not correct dimensions.

Comment: different browsers are different browsers.

Comment: It is similar to the case here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14450874/4636715

Comment: So there is no way that screen resolution cannot be reliably discovered by JavaScript?